# Google maps w/ clustering. Check whether a marker has already been rendered

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I use [`Google Maps ios utils`](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils) clustering and have set up a custom `iconView` for the `marker` & `cluster` like this:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {

      // Check if marker or cluster
      if marker.userData is PlaceMarker {

          if let userData = marker.userData as? PlaceMarker {
             marker.iconView = MarkerView(caption: userData.caption)
          }

          marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
          marker.isFlat = true
          marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop

      } else {
          // Apply custom view for cluster
          marker.iconView = ClusterViewIcon(caption: userData.caption)

          // Show clusters above markers
          marker.zIndex = 1000;
          marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
          marker.isFlat = true
          marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
      }
  }
```

`func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) { }`

get's called every time there was a zoom level change even if no clustering / declustering happened, and `makrer.iconView` is always `nil` there even if it was set up before.

How can one implement a `guard` to only setup `iconView` and other `marker` properties only when the marker is rendered for the first time? otherwise it is just a waste of resources.. (and also the animation happens on every zoom level change)

---

EDIT: One way I can think of it is to store already rendered markers `id` in an array and check against it.. but that's a dirty way..

Reference: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/96